# Ad Server does not serve ads in Firefox, but works fine in Chrome, IE, & Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, openx, advertisement-server

I'm having a strange (likely JavaScript) related issue. I'm running Open X Ad Server ( http://www.openx.org ). The ads load fine every time when visiting the site via Chrome, IE, or Safari, but sometimes don't load at all in FireFox - Hence, it is a client side issue, which leads me to believe its something up with the javascript.

The fact that the problem is intermittent, and does not through any error codes to FireBug, also doesn't make it any easier to diagnose and address.

Any ideas how to diagnose / address this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any Firefox plugins, such as [Adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/) installed? When I first visited the site in FF, no ads were shown, but after disabling the plugin, I see them.

Comment: Good idea, but its a fresh Firefox install - try hitting refresh a few times and they (should) start to disappear

Comment: Hmm, try putting your ad code on a blank HTML page and try to diagnose it there.

Comment: Good advice - will try tonight

Comment: Put the ad code on a blank HTML page, problem still exists. Beginning to think this is a bug in OpenX, but don't understand how its only affecting Firefox users!